# Правильная ли логика работы приложения на react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть 2 текстовых инпута и кнопка добавить.
После нажатия мы должны взять данные из инпутов и от рисовать их.
При нажатии на кнопку начинаем принимать данные из инпутов,
передаем в редьюсер
передаем в actions что мы получили данные
и далее в actions передает ответ в редьюсер что нужно взять принятые данные и передать их в шаблон для отрисовки
так обычно делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Данные из инпутов передаются в action
2. Вызывается соответствующий reducer в который передается текущее состояние и action
3. reducer вычисляет новое состояние и сохраняет общий store
4. Отрисовываются измененные данные

Для вашего примера не обязательно redux использовать, можно и на реакт стейте сделать.

[Документация redux. Data Flow (Поток данных)](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html)